# Why does cron fail?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

so I have these two cron jobs ( but as you can see from screens they fail, but I don't see any exception in the logs. ):
[image: Cron Fail]

```
class AddTaskHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    try:
        try:
            logging.info('trying to purge the queue')
            q = taskqueue.Queue('default')
            q.purge()
            logging.info('purge completed')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Error in purging queue, continue., e: ' + e.message)
            pass

        logging.info('adding tasks to queue started')

        taskqueue.add(url = '/tasks/popularityUpdate')
        taskqueue.add(url = '/tasks/weatherUpdate')
        taskqueue.add(url = '/tasks/Recalculation')

        logging.info('adding tasks to queue finished')

        logging.info('Removing items from cache')
        memcache.delete_multi({'news1000', 'events1000', 'music1000', 'movies1000', 'theatre1000'})
        logging.info('Removing items from cache done.')

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Exception in adding tasks to the queue, e: ' + e.message)

    self.redirect('/')
```

**Route handler:**

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/cron/addtask', AddTaskHandler),
    ('/cron/refreshInfo', RefreshHandler),
   ], debug=True)
util.run_wsgi_app(app)
```

**APP.YAML:**

```
application: **********
version: 3
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon\.ico

- url: /humans\.txt
  static_files: static/txt/humans.txt
  upload: static/txt/humans\.txt

- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: static/txt/robots.txt
  upload: static/txt/robots\.txt

- url: /.*
  script: main.py

- url: /tasks/popularityUpdate
  script: main.py

- url: /tasks/Recalculation
  script: main.py

- url: /tasks/weatherUpdate
  script: main.py

- url: /cron/addtask
  script: main.py

- url: /cron/refreshInfo
  script: main.py

builtins:
- appstats: on
```

**CRON.YAML:**

```
cron:
- description: addTaskToTheQueue
  url: /cron/addtask
  schedule: every 3 hours

- description: refreshInformation
  url: /cron/refreshInfo
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

So my question is - what is the reason gae shows it as **Failed**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Can you reach the urls that you add to the taskqueue (ie /tasks/popularityUpdate)?
- When you enter the cron job url manually, does it do what it suppose to?
- Doesn't the logs in the admin console show any errors (on the cron request)?
- Why do you have an redirect at the end of your cron-job handler (`AddTaskHandler`)? Try removing it.

..fredrik

Comment: redirect stuff was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should put the catch-all handler (/.*) in the end of the handlers section in app.yaml.
2. Test a basic /cron/addTask in the browser does it work?

Comment: 1. I did that, but did not helped. 2. It works in browser, i get redirected to (/)

Comment: 3. scroll down and you will see the routing :)

Comment: @LukasŠalkauskas My bad, can you post the update app.yaml with /.* at the end